# Jquery Increment Attribute Value by 1 on Click of Id

Tags: jquery

So, I have a list representing cards in a carousel. Each list item has a unique id, a common class, and a custom attribute "position" to indicate its order in the carousel.

```
<div class="carousel-container">
    <ul class="carousel">
      <li id="1" class="story" position="1"></li>
      <li id="2" class="story" position="5"></li>
      <li id="3" class="story" position="4"></li> 
      <li id="4" class="story" position="2"></li>
      <li id="5" class="story" position="3"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I am trying to set up an on click event where when an element with the id of "forward" is clicked, the integer value of the "position" attribute increments by 1. Similarly there will be a "backward" element id that will decrement this value.

```
  <nav class="control">
    <ul>
      <li id="forward"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-right"></i></a></li>
      <li id="backward"><a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-caret-left"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Running the following code in my browser console works perfectly

```
$('.story').attr('position', function(_, v) {
  return Number(v) + 1;
});
```

But when I set it up to execute on click, it does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#forward").click(function() {
$('.story').attr('position', function(_, v) {
  return Number(v) + 1;
});
});

$("#backward").click(function() {
  $('.story').attr('position', function(_, v) {
    return Number(v) - 1;
  });
  });
  
});
```

I am not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Your click event works just perfect. If it's not working check your console log

Comment: To demonstrate @CarstenLøvboAndersen's point, your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1q7nLzxh/. If it not working for you, open devtools and check the console for errors

Comment: Thank you both. You were correct, the code works as intended, this ended up being an issue in my UI where another element was layered overtop of my buttons, preventing me from clicking them to execute the script.